# Changing datatype of column changes behavior of query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT [Theme].[PK_Theme], [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
  FROM [Theme] 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] 
    ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
  JOIN [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme] 
 WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%'
   AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme 
   AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%'
 GROUP BY [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type], [Theme].[PK_Theme] 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [Theme].[Name]
```

The reason the `LIKE`s are there is because the `'%'` is actually parametrized using asp.net server control.

This query results in the following:

[image]

You cant see all of the returned data but `[Theme].[Name]` is in alphabetical order within two segments, 1st where `[ThemeType].[Type]` is `NULL` then where it is not null. `[Theme].[PK_Theme]` is the primary key that is associated with `[Theme].[Name]`.

The way the tables are associated is that Theme has a column called `ThemeTypeId` which is a foreign key of the primary key on the `ThemeType` table.

Now here is my issue, currently `ThemeTypeId` is of `VARCHAR(50)` data type, I need it to be `INT`. I see the issue is:

```
COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null')
```

This results in the following error:

Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value `'NULL'` to data type `int`.

However, if I change `null` to `NULL` nothing is returned, if I change it to 0 only the `NULL's are returned. I need both`NULL` and non-Null returned as was previously accomplished above. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you still putting `like '%'` after the coalesce, even when it's an int?

Comment: currently, yes... is this incorrect? How would you return all values in the case of ints

Comment: I'll come up with a possible answer, but without knowing your server control I doubt I'll get it 100% first time; feel free to make suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to remove the line

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%'
```

from the `where` clause.  The `like` is doing an `is not null`, and you are converting `NULL` values anyway.  So the line is not needed.

If you cannot do that, can you do this?

```
AND COALESCE(cast([THEME].[THEMETYPEID] as varchar(255)), 'null') LIKE '%'
```

Or this?

```
AND [THEME].[THEMETYPEID] is not null
```

Comment: AND COALESCE(cast([THEME].[THEMETYPEID] as varchar(255)), 'null') LIKE '%' works perfect and currently works with how my server controls are functioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an int instead of a varchar, you need to alter the following line:

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%'
```

to something like

```
AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 0) = 0%
```

This assumes that `%` is simply replaced by the numeric value when one is supplied, and a blank for null. If is more complex than that, the '%' may need to appear more than once in this query (which your control may not support).